# Editing CSS Header Info Reverts Wordpress Website Back to Default Settings

Tags: css, wordpress

I purchased a Wordpress theme and I'm trying to change some wording on the "Description" line. However, if I change anything, all my styling changes are lost and my website reverts back to the default theme settings (logo, color scheme, etc.)

What causes this? Is this some sort of embedded theme author protection?

```
/*<br>
Theme Name:<br>
Author:<br>
Author URI:<br>
<b>Description:</b><br>
License:<br>
License URI:<br>
Tags:<br>
Text Domain:<br>
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Theme Name (*): Name of the theme.
Theme URI: The URL of a public web page where users can find more information about the theme.
Author (*): The name of the individual or organization who developed the theme. Using the Theme Author’s wordpress.org username is recommended.
Author URI: The URL of the authoring individual or organization.
Description (*): A short description of the theme.
Version (*): The version, written in X.X or X.X.X format.
License (*): The license of the theme.
License URI (*): The URL of the theme license.
Text Domain (*): The string used for textdomain for translation.
Tags: Words or phrases that allow users to find the theme using the tag filter. A full list of tags is in the Theme Review Handbook.
Domain Path: Used so that WordPress knows where to find the translation when the theme is disabled. Defaults to /languages.
```

Style.css for a Child Theme #Style.css for a Child Theme
If your theme is a Child Theme, the Template line is required in style.css header.

```
/*
Theme Name: My Child Theme
Template: Twenty Seventeen
*/
```

More explain on WordPress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your answer... I'm not running a child theme. All I'm trying to do is change some wording on the Description line of the existing CSS header, but when I do, my site reverts back to the themes' default design settings.